# 'this' implicitly.... how to solve this

Tags: javascript, typescript, pdf, vuejs3

**'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.**

I want to preview my pdfFile using pdfjs-dist but I don't know why I can't use this.$refs.pdfViewer.

I followed the steps with the instructor in the video. but encountered this problem.

```
onpdf(e: any) {
  this.pdfFile = e.target.files[0];
  // Did i miss something here?
  if (this.pdfFile.type == "application/pdf") {
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function () {
      let pdfData = new Uint8Array(this.result as any);
      let loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({ data: pdfData });
      loadingTask.promise.then(function (pdf) {
        console.log("PDF loaded");

        let pageNumber = 1;
        pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(
          function (page) {
            console.log("Page loaded");

            let scale = 1.5;
            let viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: scale });

            let canvas = this.$refs.pdfViewer; // *this* here is the ploblem
            let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            canvas.height = viewport.height;
            canvas.width = viewport.width;

            let renderContext = {
              canvasContext: context,
              viewport: viewport,
            };
            let renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
            renderTask.promise.then(function () {
              console.log("Page rendered");
            });
          },
          function (reason) {
            console.error(reason);
          },
        );
      });
    };
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.pdfFile);
  }
}
```

```
    <input @change="onpdf"/>

    <canvas ref="pdfViewer"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will not be a correct `this` scope in the `pdfjs` callback.

Grab a reference to the canvas before it. (I also flipped the `if` statement for less nesting and turned your `.then`s into proper `async` for clarity.)

```
onpdf(e: any) {
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  if (file.type !== 'application/pdf') {
    return;
  }
  this.pdfFile = file;
  const canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = this.$refs.pdfViewer;  // <- moved here!
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = async function () {
    const pdfData = new Uint8Array(this.result as any);
    const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({data: pdfData});
    const pdf = await loadingTask.promise;
    console.log('PDF loaded');

    const pageNumber = 1;
    const page = await pdf.getPage(pageNumber);
    console.log('Page loaded');
    const scale = 1.5;
    const viewport = page.getViewport({scale});
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    const renderContext = {
      canvasContext: context,
      viewport,
    };
    const renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
    await renderTask.promise;
    console.log('Page rendered');
  };
  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.pdfFile);
}
```

Comment: I'm almost done it but this happen Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'HTMLCanvasElement'. In  const *canvas* : HTMLCanvasElement = this.$refs.pdfViewer;

I'm using typescript.

Comment: Then cast that. `const canvas = this.$refs.pdfViewer as HTMLCanvasViewer;`

Comment: It useful. but when I run this, the console said Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getDocument') at fileReader.onload

Comment: Well, then `pdfjsLib` isn't loaded for whichever reason, and that's an entirely different question.